# C# - Apply attribute to method conditionally from app.config

Tags: c#, selenium, custom-attributes, preprocessor-directive

**TLDR;**
*How can I create a pre-processing directive in C# based on values from an app.config file?*

I am using Selenium to do integration testing. I have two test method classes which are responsible for testing different areas of my application. My test classes are identified as such with a `[TestClass]` attribute, and my test methods are identified using a `[TestMethod]` attribute like so:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestsForAreaX
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFoo()
    {
        //Do test logic here
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestBar()
    {
      //Do test logic here
    }
}
```

When I rebuild my solution all methods that have had the `[TestMethod]` applied will appear in the test explorer.

What I would now like to do is add some flags to my app.config to conditionally apply `[TestMethod]` attributes so that I can specify which tests I want run. The reason for this is that some tests are taking very long and I would like to exclude them without having to fiddle with method attributes directly.

I am aware of pre-processing directives like:

```
#if DEBUG
    //debug mode
#elif
    //release mode
#endif
```

but that only works for build configurations and not values in app config files, unless I am mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove the attributes of the assembly after compilation. Maybe you are looking for Categories:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestsForAreaX
{
    [TestCategory("LongRunning"), TestMethod]
    public void TestFoo()
    {
        //Do test logic here
    }
    [TestCategory("ShortRunning"), TestMethod]
    public void TestBar()
    {
      //Do test logic here
    }
} enter code here
```

Then you can run tests for different categories at least from the command line, this site explains how:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing that I was looking for. I have no problem with using a command line either. Ty.